# Flot plotting wrong points

Tags: jquery, flot

```
var plot = $.plot($("#statsChart"), [{
    data: [
        [1, 2],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 0],
        [4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0],
        [7, 0],
        [8, 0],
        [9, 0],
        [10, 0],
        [11, 0],
        [12, 0]
    ],
    label: "Serviços ativos"
}, {
    data: [
        [1, 2],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 0],
        [4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0],
        [7, 0],
        [8, 0],
        [9, 0],
        [10, 0],
        [11, 0],
        [12, 0]
    ],
    label: "Serviços em processo"
}, {
    data: [
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 0],
        [4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0],
        [7, 0],
        [8, 0],
        [9, 0],
        [10, 0],
        [11, 0],
        [12, 0]
    ],
    label: "Registos"
}], {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 1,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: {
                colors: [{
                    opacity: 0.1
                }, {
                    opacity: 0.13
                }]
            }
        },
        points: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 2,
            radius: 3
        },
        shadowSize: 0,
        stack: true
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        tickColor: "#f9f9f9",
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    legend: {
        // show: false
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#fff"
    },
    colors: ["#343e4b", "#7e91aa", "#4387bf", "#3b9ff3"],
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [
            [1, "JAN"],
            [2, "FEV"],
            [3, "MAR"],
            [4, "ABR"],
            [5, "MAI"],
            [6, "JUN"],
            [7, "JUL"],
            [8, "AGO"],
            [9, "SET"],
            [10, "OUT"],
            [11, "NOV"],
            [12, "DEZ"]
        ],
        font: {
            size: 12,
            family: "Open Sans, Arial",
            variant: "small-caps",
            color: "#697695"
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        ticks: 3,
        tickDecimals: 0,
        font: {
            size: 12,
            color: "#9da3a9"
        }
    }
});

function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y - 30,
        left: x - 50,
        color: "#fff",
        padding: '2px 5px',
        'border-radius': '6px',
        'background-color': '#000',
        opacity: 0.80
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}
var previousPoint = null;
$("#statsChart").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(0),
                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);
            var month = item.series.xaxis.ticks[item.dataIndex].label;
            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                item.series.label + " of " + month + ": " + y);
        }
    } else {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        previousPoint = null;
    }
});
```

But the problem is that when the plot is made on "Serviços Ativos" (first data entry) show's correct data and then the second entry ("serviços em processo") does not appear instead appears the last entry ("Registos") with a value of 4 when it should be 0.

This plot was made using flot, i've tryed using variables to set the data the output it's the same.

Also i've already checked the coder documentation and everything seems to be coded correctly.

Any Help?

(Flot github: https://github.com/flot/flot)

### UPDATE

Solved, removed the jquery.flot.stack.js and jquery.flot.resize.js that fixed the problem

Comment: Olá Pedro! Your code looks good to me. I made a jsFiddle with your code and looked good to me. Then I made __[this one](http://jsfiddle.net/3V92T/)__ where I added some points with value `10` just so the data would be more clear. Please explain better what is wrong in your data.

Comment: Here is the problem... I removed the local file and linked to the one on the server to be sure that the file it's up to date... And entered the code of your seccond jsFiddle, the one that you gave me the link and looks nothing a like... Here is hte [image](http://http://pcdev.pt/1.png) on my server for full res

Comment: Already solved... I had these to scripts jquery.flot.stack.js and jquery.flot.resize.js and removing them solved the problem... I've noitced in your fiddle you had only the jquery.flot.js

Comment: Pedro, those files are plugins. If you don't need them you should remove them, but they are usefull in some cases. Just removing them is hidding the problem. But if it works for you, great. Maybe you can delete this question if you found the solution.

Comment: Oh, and btw, welcome to visit http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ some day.

Comment: Pedro, you can answer your own question if you've found the answer that worked for you, that way you can mark it as answered.